# how to dynamically display the EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout

i'm new to android. So can any one help me to get the following, when i enter the number in a EditText, the entered no.of EdidText should be appear dynamically. For example if i entered 3 in a EditText then, 3 EditText(no.of) have to be shown on the screen. How can i show this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to your EditText by calling [EditText.addTextChangedListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29). Then in your TextWatcher wait for calls to afterTextChanged and count the characters and update your title. This will be easier if you make your Activity implement the the TextWatcher interface itself.

Answer (score 0):

Add layout to your xml where you want to display the Edittext.
Then create the Layout variable e.g

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id...);
```

and create new textboxes and add to the linearlayout e.g

```
EditText[] edit = new EditText[]();
EditText[] edit= new EditText[entered number];
```

initialize the variables in the loop by new Edittext(context);
and add each one to the Layout

```
`ll.addView(edit[iterator]);`
```

Comment: Hi shah thanks for ur reply.. Any how i got the expected output.but the problem is, once a have displayed no.of EditText then again enter another no. for example first i entered 3. I overwrite 2 it shows 3+2=5 EditText.How to iver come this?

Comment: Here is my code:edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
                value = edit.getText().toString();
                no = Integer.parseInt(value);
                for(int i = 0; i< no; i++ )
                { linearlayout.addView(createNewViews()); }           
              } });

Comment: before adding views write following line linearlayout.removeAllViews();